# typename gives strange result - in codeblocks

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

This code from main:

```
Int<> a;
    cout << typeid(Int<>::range_type).name();
```

gives output 'x' while compiled in codeblocks with gcc 4.6.1. Any reason for that?

```
template<class Int_T>
struct Best_Fit
{//evaluate it lazily ;)
    typedef typename if_<std::is_signed<Int_T>::value,Signed_Type,Unsigned_Type>::type type;
};

template<class Int_T = int, typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Min_Range = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::min(), typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type Max_Range = std::numeric_limits<Int_T>::max()>
class Int {
    public:
    typedef decltype(Min_Range) range_type;
};
```

Comment: I added C++11 because you use C++11 features (`constexpr`, `decltype`).

Answer (score 5):

`typename Best_Fit<Int_T>::type` in the instantiation you do will yield `Signed_Type`. Since you don't show its definition, we have no idea what type that is. But `c++filt -t x` says it is `long long`.

Recall that `typeid(...).name()` can yield whatever name it wants. GNU libstdc++ yields the mangled type name.

Comment: @litb where can I learn how to use c++filt? Tried google but without much success.